# Generate an Asymmetric NxM matrix whose Rows and Columns Independently Sum to 1

Tags: python, matrix, random, linear-algebra

Given a target matrix size of N rows and M columns, is it possible to pick values such that all rows and columns sum to 1, **on the condition that** the matrix is not symmetric across the diagonal? Here's a target matrix I was able to generate when N==M (The problems arise when N!=M - see below):

```
[[0.08345877 0.12844672 0.90911941 0.41964704 0.57709569]
 [0.53949086 0.07965491 0.62582134 0.48922244 0.38357809]
 [0.80619328 0.27581426 0.31312973 0.26855717 0.4540732 ]
 [0.11803505 0.88201276 0.1990759  0.2818701  0.63677383]
 [0.57058968 0.75183898 0.07062126 0.6584709  0.06624682]]
```

I'm writing this in numpy. Currently I've written the following (brute force) code, which I know works when n==m. However, if n != m, rowwise and columwise sums don't converge to 0, **and** the ratio of rowwise sums to columwise sums converges to (n/m):

```
n,m = (5,4)
mat = np.random.random((n,m))
for i in range(100):
    s0 = mat.sum(0)
    s1 = mat.sum(1)[:,newaxis]
    mat = (mat/s0)
    mat = (mat/s1)
    if i%10 == 0:
        print(s0[0]/s1[0,0])
```

The final output in this case is 1.25 (I.e. n/m, or 5/4). I'm beginning to think this might not be mathematically possible. Can someone prove me wrong?

Comment: It is impossible. If you add all N row sums together, you have the sum of all the elements in the matrix, and since each row sum is 1, you get N. But adding all M column sums together, you again have the sum of all the elements in the matrix, but this time you get M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are correct, the problem cannot be solved if N != M.

Take a 2x3 matrix as an example:

```
[[a b c]
 [d e f]]
```

Assume that all rows and all columns sum to 1 and show a contradiction. The rows sum to 1 so:

```
a+b+c = 1
d+e+f = 1
```

This gives:

```
(a+b+c)+(d+e+f) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Now look at the columns.  Each column also sums to 1 so we have:

```
a+d = 1
b+e = 1
c+f = 1
```

Combining the three column equations gives:

```
(a+d)+(b+e)+(c+f) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

Since the sum of all six matrix elements cannot be both 2 and 3 simultaneously, `2 != 3`, the initial assumption leads to a contradiction and so is disproved.  More generally the problem cannot be solved for N != M with N rows and M columns.

The contradiction disappears when N = M for a square matrix.